# Prolog - Apply procedure to specific list members

Tags: list, prolog, nested

I've got a function which takes a list, and removes all unique elements in that list:

```
repeating(Q, L):-
        repeating(Q, Q, L).
repeating([], _, []).
repeating([H | T], Q, [H | L]):-
        count(H, Q, N),
         N > 1, !,
        repeating(T, Q, L).
repeating([H | T], Q, L):-
        count(H, Q, N),
        N = 1,
        repeating(T, Q, L).
```

for example the query

```
 repeating([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 7, 7, 3, 8], X).
```

gives

```
 X = [2, 3, 2, 7, 7, 3].
```

I want to apply this to a list made up of four element long lists, checking only the third element, such that, for example

```
   repeating([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [3, 5, 7, 9], [4, 3, 2, 1]], X).
```

would return

```
   X = [[5, 6, 7, 8], [3, 5, 7, 9].
```

only the lists which had non-unique third elements. My code as now only applies to simple lists such as the first one, and I've spent all morning trying to come up with a way to modify it to apply to cases such as these for an arbitrarily long list of four element long lists, but have not been able to find a way to do so, and would very much appreciate some guidance on this.

Thanks.

Comment: This change would impact `count` but may not impact `repeating` at all. In `count`, treat the element you're counting as `[_,_,X,_]` and count the matching third elements. `repeating`, I think, may remain unchanged since it's not constraining your list to atomic elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a function to retrieve the third element of each list, and then adapt your code by checking those elements

```
%get the third element of a list
third([_,_,E|_], E).

%Build a list made of the third elements of the input list
buildthirdslist([],[]).
buildthirdslist([X|Xl],[Th|Thl]):-
    third(X,Th),
    buildthirdslist(Xl,Thl).


%Your code adapted
repeatingthirds(Q, L):-
    buildthirdslist(Q,Ths),
        repeatingthirds(Q, Ths, L).

repeatingthirds([], _, []).

repeatingthirds([H | T], Q, [H | L]):-
    third(H,Th),
        count(Th, Q, N),
         N > 1, !,
        repeatingthirds(T, Q, L).

repeatingthirds([H | T], Q, L):-
    third(H,Th),
        count(Th, Q, N),
        N = 1,
        repeatingthirds(T, Q, L).
```

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant, as soon as I read it I was very impressed. It's very simple and does perfectly just what I was after, and even I am able to read the code and easily understand what's happening. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little variation from Guillermo's solution. This one leaves your `repeating` predicate unchanged and uses a different `count`:

```
repeating(Q, L):-
        repeating(Q, Q, L).
repeating([], _, []).
repeating([H | T], Q, [H | L]):-
        count(H, Q, N),
        N > 1, !,
        repeating(T, Q, L).
repeating([H | T], Q, L):-
        count(H, Q, N),
        N = 1,
        repeating(T, Q, L).

count(H, Q, N) :-
    count(H, Q, 0, N).
count([_,_,E,_], [[_,_,E,_]|T], A, N) :-
    A1 is A + 1,
    count([_,_,E,_], T, A1, N).
count([_,_,E,_], [[_,_,X,_]|T], A, N) :-
    E \= X,
    count([_,_,E,_], T, A, N).
count(_, [], A, A).
```

Quick test:

```
| ?- repeating([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [3, 5, 7, 9], [4, 3, 2, 1]], X).

X = [[5,6,7,8],[3,5,7,9]] ? a

no
```

| ?-